# Changing the decimal separator in the firefox web browser

Tags: linux, firefox, browser, linux-mint

I don't know how but the decimal separator in the Firefox web browser in my laptop changed from point(dot) to comma. I found it in the Downloads section of Firefox. How to I revert it back? Just in case: Linux Mint is the operating system and the decimal separator is still dot in the OS.

Comment: When did it change? After an update to Firefox, perhaps? You might want to go back to a previous version to verify this. If it's a regression, report to Bugzilla.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN I cannot recall as to when it happened. I guess it should have occurred after an update.